# app.get("/api/current_user".. not firing after passport.js authenticated. NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am new to NodeJS. And I am trying to create a simple web server.
I am only using NodeJS and Passport.js (using a google strategy) right now.

Currently, all the app.get("") calls are working when I am not authenticated, but once I authenticate with google and the callback happens, I can no longer access any of the app.get routes. I try and put a break point in the arrow function and it is never calls, and just hangs when loading from the browser with auth cookie.

Here is my current code:

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,   //30 days
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

authRoutes.js

```
   const passport = require('passport');

   module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get(
        "/auth/google",
        passport.authenticate('google', {
            scope: ['profile', 'email']
        })
    );

    app.get(
        '/auth/google/callback',
        passport.authenticate('google')
    );

    app.get("/api/logout", (req, res) => {
        req.logout();
        res.send(req.user);
    });

    app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {
            res.send("test");//req.user);   //Tried as a test, is called when    
                                           //not authenticated, but does not get 
                                          //called when authenticated
    });
   }
```

passport.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const googleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const User = mongoose.model("users");

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
 done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=> {
    User.findById(id)
    .then(user =>{
        doen(null, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new googleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: keys.googleclientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id })
        .then((existingUser) => {
            if (existingUser){
                //we already have a user
                done(null, existingUser);
            }
            else{
                new User({ googleId: profile.id })
                .save()
                .then (user => done(null, user));                
            }
        });
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

this probably wont help anyone besides for the fact to check for TYPOS!

I found my problem here:

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=> {
    User.findById(id)
    .then(user =>{
        doen(null, user);
    });
});
```

notice doen should be done

I got no error messages that helped me on this one.